# Migrating Indian language data from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, utf-8, migration, database-migration

I am migrating data from SQL Server database to MySQL database.

Few tables have data in languages other than English. Data is mostly in popular Indian languages like Hindi, Marathi, etc.

I check those tables, and found that fields containing data in other languages have been declared as:

> Description nvarchar

For these kind of fields, I have created fields in MySQL as follows

> Description longtext (with utf8_general_ci collation)

am I missing something, so should these settings work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  If you can get the HEX of a couple of the Indian characters, we can verify whether it is encoded in utf8.  (In utf8, the hex for one Indian *character* is generally 3 *bytes* `E0 xx yy`.)  Assuming that it is utf8, then declaring the table/column to be `CHARACTER SET utf8` would let it easily accept the characters.  You must also declare that your *client* is talking in utf8.  What client?

I recommend nothing bigger than `MEDIUMTEXT` (which allows 16M bytes, probably more than adequate) or `TEXT` (64KB) instead of `LONGTEXT` (4GB limit).

I am not familiar with the differences between `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` *collations* when it comes to Indian character sets.  If there are "combining accents" and other things that need special attention when ordering and sorting the characters, then `utf8_unicode_ci` may be preferred.  Otherwise, stick with the simpler `utf8_general_ci`.  If you can point me at a web page (in English) that discusses "how to order Hindi (etc) words", then I might be able to help.  And I might even learn something to put in [my blog on charsets and collations](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).